# Дублирование записей в mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Есть приложение написанное на node expressjs, база используется mongodb.

Алгоритм такой: когда приходят пост данные, производится поиск записи по полям `name`, `server`, `fraction`. Если такая запись есть то обновить, если нет то создать.

Проблема в том, что при большом количестве запросов, если не находит запись, то создает не одну запись, а несколько. Я предполагаю что пока mongodb создает запись, следующий поиск не дает результата, ведь запись еще не создана и поиск не дает результата, и mongodb создает еще одну идентичную запись, хотя должна обновить.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Не имел дела с mongoDB, но, навскидку, беглый поиск по документации вывел на метод `insertOne` (или `insertMany`) с параметром `upsert: true`. Судя по описанию, он делает то же, что описано в вопросе (`"Если такая запись есть то обновить, если нет то создать."`), только не средствами внешнего кода, а средствами самой базы. Более чем вероятно, что в этом случае дубликаты создаваться не будут. Пусть знающие люди подтвердят или опровергнут. :)

Comment: Можно ссылочку на документацию по методу inserOne.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/   обновляйте (update) с флагом upsert, это то, что вам нужно, если документа нет, он будет создан.

Comment: Во, знающие люди правильно говорят, у `update` тоже есть флаг `upsert`, до этого мой беглый поиск меня не довел. :) Значит, именно `update` Вам и нужен. :)